# I'm not able to retrieve cookie even though I see it in the developer tools

Tags: php, wordpress

Here is my code,(the first function is just logging it to the console) that I put in the mu-plugins directory. I can see the cookie just fine in the developer tools but can't seem to display it. The function is definitely getting hit.

```
function debug_to_console( $data ) {

    if ( is_array( $data ) )
        $output = "<script>console.log( 'Debug Objects: " . implode( ',', $data) . "' );</script>";
    else
        $output = "<script>console.log( 'Debug Objects: " . $data . "' );</script>";

    echo $output;
}

function get_login_details(){
    if(isset($_COOKIE['wordpress_test_cookie'])){
        debug_to_console($_COOKIE['wordpress_test_cookie']);
    }
}
```

Comment: how are you returning/echoing that `debug_to_console()` function or whatever function? and cookies are only active on 2nd page load, not initial. Edit: *Tap, tap, tap....*

Comment: get_login_details is called in my wordpress header template which then calls debug_to_console to display the cookie if it exists. I had it logging random text to make sure it was being called, and it worked fine. Its only when I try to get the cookie that it fails

Comment: check for errors then, see if anything comes of it.